# How to filter by calculated field using Querydsl Predicate (BooleanExpression) with Spring Data?

Tags: java, querydsl

There're two numeric columns in database like actual and plan.

I can add third column like difference and write WHERE part of query filtering by this column.

But instead having additional column in database, I want to calculate it in Predicate.

Something like (qProduct.actualPrice - qProduct.planPrice).gt(20L)

Entity:

```
public class Product {
    private String type;
    private Long actualPrice;
    private Long planPrice;
}
```

Predicate:

```
QProduct qProduct = QProduct.product;
BooleanExpression predicate = qProduct.type.eq("pizza")
            .and((qProduct.actualPrice - qProduct.planPrice).gt(20L));

Page<Product> productPage = productRepository.findAll(predicate, pageable);
```

Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the subtract method of [NumberExpression](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.0.3/apidocs/com/querydsl/core/types/dsl/NumberExpression.html#subtract-N-) class

```
QProduct qProduct = QProduct.product;
BooleanExpression predicate = qProduct.type.eq("pizza")
          .and((qProduct.actualPrice.subtract(qProduct.planPrice)).gt(20L));

Page<Product> productPage = productRepository.findAll(predicate, pageable);
```